# Remove space in keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d={'A ':[],'B '=[]}
```

I want to remove the whitespace before the quote and produce the following:

```
d={'A':[],'B'=[]}

for k,v in d.items():
    k=k.replace(" ","")
pprint.pprint(d)
```

I expect the above code to remove space before the quote,but the output is same as previous dictionary
I also tried k=k.strip(),which produced the same result

I will be thankful if somebody can suggest me the solution

Comment: or using a dict comprehension, `{k.strip():v for (k,v) in d.items()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> d={'A ':[],'B ':[]}
>>> new_d ={}
>>> for k, v in d.items():
        new_d[k.strip()] = v


>>> d
{'A ': [], 'B ': []}
>>> new_d
{'A': [], 'B': []}
```

btw, you have syntax error in your question. Your are writing `'B '=[]` instead of `'B ': []`

Answer (score 2):

you can create a new `dict` object with modified keys,

```
d={'A ':[],'B ':[]}

d = dict((k.strip(), v) for k, v in d.items())
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is error in your declaration of the dictionary, as in this

```
d={'A ':[],'B '=[]}
```

needs to be changed to this

```
d={'A ':[],'B ':[]}
```

As for your answer, you could try creating a new dictionary

```
from pprint import pprint
d={'A ':[],'B ':[]}
new_d = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    new_d[k.strip()] = v

pprint(new_d)
```